# Manipulation events from ItemsControl not passed to parent (page) in Windows Phone 8.1 RT application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, itemscontrol

The manipulation events like

ManipulationStarted
ManipulationCompleted

are not working when we swipe on top of ItemsControl in Windows phone 8.1 RT application. Either the manipulation events are not routed to the parent or not fired at all in this case.

I tried to set ManipulationMode="All" on ItemsControl but that does not help. I want to load the prevous page when the user swipe from left to right on top of list displayed using ItemsControl.

Update:

Adding ManipulationMode="All" to ItemsPresenter like below solved the issue (manipulation events passed to parent i.e page) but vertical scrolling is not working anymore.

```
    <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">

                    <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter" ManipulationMode="All"/>
                   </ScrollViewer>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
```

In Windows phone 8 / Windows phone 8.1 silverlight application this problem is not observed.